ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database in Azure error log
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database is the error i can see when looking into the web app logs in Azure.
Im sure my database.py is in the same dir as the main.py and when i run it locally it works. i run it locally with: uvicorn main:app --reload. This works.
when i deploy it, it succeeds in GIT, it says deployed. But when i check the web service azure LOG it says the no database found. for the startup command in azure i use: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
Picture of LOG 
For context: im using a github repo as deployment center in azure(and im trying to deploy a fastapi backend)
Looked on stack overflow for someone who had a similar problem, looked on youtube.
Github repo: https://github.com/DeNaamIsDaaf/Backend-FastAPI/tree/main

Can you share your github repo if possible ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@SirraSneha i updated my question, could you perhaps look again? I hope this information suffices :)

Based on the log stream provided, the error might be related to the startup command in the configuration of the Azure App Service.
I created a simple FastAPI application and successfully deployed it to Azure App Service without any issues.
WorkflowFile :
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - Sfastapitest1
on:
push:
branches:
- main
workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
- name: Set up Python version
uses: actions/setup-python@v1
with:
python-version: '3.12'
- name: Create and start virtual environment
run: |
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
- name: Install dependencies
run: pip install -r requirements.txt
- name: Zip artifact for deployment
run: zip release.zip ./* -r
- name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
with:
name: python-app
path: |
release.zip
!venv/
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
needs: build
environment:
name: 'Production'
url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
steps:
- name: Download artifact from build job
uses: actions/download-artifact@v
with:
name: python-app
- name: Unzip artifact for deployment
run: unzip release.zip
- name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
id: deploy-to-webapp
with:
app-name: 'Sfastapitest1'
slot-name: 'Production'
```yaml
publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<SecretKey>}}

It was successfully deployed to Azure app service

Configure the below startup command in your Azure app service
gunicorn --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 600 --access-logfile '-' --error-logfile '-' app:app


Here's the output after deployment:

